# Suma de las horas que entre dos fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber como podria sacar las horas entre fecha_ini y fecha_fin

```
EQUIPO    TIPO_MANTE    FECHA_INI    FECHA_FIN   Horas   TOTAL
LAPTOP        A         12/20/18     12/21/18    24       50
DESKTOP       A         12/20/18     12/21/18    24       400
LAPTOP        A         12/20/18     12/23/18    72       100
LAPTOP        B         12/21/18     12/22/18    24       200
LAPTOP        A         12/22/18     12/24/18    24       50
```

que en este caso asi seria mi consulta para sacar las horas

```
SELECT S.Equipo, S.Tipo_mante, HOUR( TIMEDIFF( T.Fecha_fin, T.Fecha_ini ) ) 
AS  `difirencia` 
FROM orden_trabajo t
LEFT JOIN solicitud_mante s ON S.Id_soli = T.Id_soli
WHERE S.Tipo_mante =  'Inmediato'
GROUP BY S.Equipo, S.Tipo_mante
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

Pero seria que si el mismo EQUIPO Y EL MISMO MANTENIMIENTO se repiten que vaya sumando las horas he probado para hacer la suma pero me da error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo deberías añadir el rango de fechas a tu consulta,

Tus variables en PHP serían $FI para fecha inicial, y $FF para fecha final

```
SELECT S.Equipo, S.Tipo_mante, SUM( t.Total ) AS TOTAL
FROM solicitud_mante s
LEFT JOIN orden_trabajo t ON s.Id_soli = t.Id_soli
WHERE (S.Tipo_mante =  "Inmediato") AND (S.Fecha_fin BETWEEN '$FI' AND '$FF')
GROUP BY S.Equipo, S.Tipo_mante
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```